# Orchard CMS: Sending data to template manually

Tags: razor, orchardcms, taxonomy, orchardcms-1.8

I am rendering BlogPosts in a Taxonomy list page. I have two Taxonomy fields on each post and want to display Terms for one. I can get these Terms with:

`var d = item.As<TermsPart>().Terms.Where(t => t.Field == "TaxonomyA").ToList();`

What form must the data (d) take for Display to properly render using TaxonomyField.cshtml?

Comment: The question is unclear. What is it exactly that you're trying to do?

Comment: I want to do `@Display(d)` and have the current Taxonomy Field template render my terms. I figured reusing the existing templates is the correct way to go. I'm trying to figure out what form of d Display requires. IList<TermContentItem> from above didn't work.

Comment: `@Display` takes a shape, not a content item or a list of content items. What template are you attempting to do that from?

Comment: OK. I'm in TermPart alternate, going through a list of BlogPosts that display for a Term. I only want to show the Terms for the Taxonomy I'm listing for.
I know how to build the display with what I have (list of ContentItems), but it is just a duplication of what is already in a template. Figured it would be better to just call the template.

Comment: Right, so then you have to hand it the kind of shape it expects, not a content item. You can either craft your own shape, or ask the `ContentManager` to `BuildDisplay` for your term content item, which will turn it into a bunch of shapes.